How to get any value from the FastForm.of which always is going to return a null
I found this package which I found to be pretty cool, but I am not sure if I don't know how to get values from the fields, or if this is a bug. Could anyone help me to understand this?
Flutter code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_fast_forms/flutter_fast_forms.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'FastForm Bug Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FastForm Bug Demo'),
      ),
      body: const MyForm(),
    );
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyForm({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyForm> createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void _onSubmit() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState?.save();
      final FastFormState? form = FastForm.of(context);

      // This will always be null, demonstrating the bug
      print('Form state: $form');

      if (form != null) {
        final String? email = form.getFieldByName('email')?.value as String?;
        final String? password = form.getFieldByName('password')?.value as String?;
        print('Email: $email');
        print('Password: $password');
      } else {
        print('FastForm.of(context) returned null');
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: FastForm(
        formKey: _formKey,
        children: [
          FastTextField(
            name: 'email',
            labelText: 'Email',
            validator: Validators.compose([
              Validators.required((value) => 'Email is required'),
            ]),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16),
          FastTextField(
            name: 'password',
            labelText: 'Password',
            obscureText: true,
            validator: Validators.required((value) => 'Password is required'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _onSubmit,
            child: const Text('Submit'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Every single time the _formKey.currentState!.validate()  will be true, but I will get the form from FastForm.of(context) it will always be null. Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks
